# Update marker sizes of a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

A scatter plot object has a method called `.set_array` to update the colours of the markers and `.set_offsets` to update their position but how can I update the marker sizes?

I need this for fast real time plotting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to as a scatter plot object, but when you call `plt.scatter`, the function accepts a keyword argument `s`, which you can use to dictate the marker's size. You may also want to change `linewidth`.

Comment: @Praveen : I want to be able to change the marker size after plotting without having to clear the axes and re-plot.

Comment: I'm not able to find a way to change the markers' sizes after they've been plotted. But as an aside, I have been able to make fast real time (line) plots in the past. I used to save the lines every time they were plotted, and delete them from the axis before plotting a new set (without actually calling `clf` on the figure). I'd then use `draw()` to re-draw the axis. All this with `plt.ion()` of course. Perhaps you can find a similar method with `scatter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is doable, with using a magic method (`_size`). Use it with caution, as it may become broken in future releases:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y=range(10), range(10)
sca=plt.scatter(x,y)
raw_input()
sca._sizes=(5+np.arange(10))*10 #you can set you markers to different sizes
plt.draw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The method to update the sizes of the scatter points is called [`.set_sizes()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.set_sizes)

```
scat = plt.scatter(x,y)
scat.set_sizes(sizes)
```

where `sizes` must be an array or list of same length as `x` and `y`.